# Can't get Apache to serve django admin static files

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to deploy Django to apache but can't get it to serve my static admin files. It seems to be looking for them under /var/www/static and I can't seem to be able to change that.

The admin site seem to be working except for styling. I get a title and a log in form. My django app is working too. It's the static files for the admin that aren't served.

Using Django 1.4.1.

The files are under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static and linked to from /home/dutt/vaccapp/backend/static/admin.

The apache error log says this

```
[Sun Sep 30 10:57:20 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] File does not exist: /var/www/home, referer: http://dathui.example.com/vaccapp/admin/
[Sun Sep 30 10:57:20 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] File does not exist: /var/www/home, referer: http://dathui.example.com/vaccapp/admin/
```

But I'm not sure how to change it.

In my django site config I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin me@host.com

    ServerRoot "/home/dutt/vaccapp"
    DocumentRoot "/home/dutt/vaccapp"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/dutt/vaccapp/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "/home/dutt/vaccapp/backend/static/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

ServerRoot is not set in apache2.conf.

From my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/dutt/vaccapp/backend/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Nothing added to STATICFILES_DIRS.

This is added to my apache2.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /vaccapp /home/dutt/vaccapp/backend/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/dutt/vaccapp

<Directory /home/dutt/vaccapp>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is set by default to `/static/admin/` # Deprecated in Django 1.4 (now using `STATIC_URL + 'admin/'`. The result is the same.

Here's the fixes to the apache config:

```
Alias /static/admin "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
Alias /static "/home/dutt/vaccapp/backend/static"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

And the WsgiScriptAlias had to be moved from the main apache config into the VirtualHost.

After a long discussion we found the problem was that Django did not install the admin static properly ... they were symlinked to eachother (very weird). A Django reinstall fixed it and it worked fine now.

Comment: Is your app working with this configuration? Is your app's package name `backend`.

Comment: App is working but it's a backend so it doesn't use any static files. Project name is backend, app name is dbaccess.

Comment: It would seem that Apache is looking for your files in its default location, so first thing is add a `ServerRoot` to the `VirtualHost` (this would not be necessary if your WSGIAlias would serve / . Would be nice to have the exact request URL too though. Give us some access_logs with 404's.

Comment: I tried adding ServerRoot to the VirtualHost but that didn't seem to change anything. I'm looking at the apache2/error.log file and I can't find any 404, just the "File does not exist /var/www/static, refererer .../vaccapp/admin" lines. Q updated with the exact ServerRoot.

Comment: Check the access.log file ... it should be in the same directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17346/discussion-between-igor-serko-and-dutt)

Comment: This helped me.. setup my Alias as described in my django.conf.. all is well

Answer (score 1):

My low reputation forces me to write a whole answer to add a small detail to Igor's answer.

I simply added the apache config part to my configuration, but it was not sufficient. I had to change:

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
```

to

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin"
```

both in the first `Alias` and in the `<Directory>` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Blazor I had to use a small variation of the original. My setup includes graphite-web, which is using django admin. I'm just posting it for reference.

My apache's virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName graphite.myhost.com
    Redirect permanent / https://graphite.myhost.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName graphite.myhost.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/graphite.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl_graphite.key
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

    WSGIDaemonProcess _graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120 user=_graphite group=_graphite
    WSGIProcessGroup _graphite
    WSGIImportScript /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi process-group=_graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi

    AliasMatch ^/admin/(.*)static/admin(.*)$ /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/$2
    <Directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /content/ /usr/share/graphite-web/static/
    <Location "/content/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    <Location "/">
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Zone"
            AuthBasicProvider wsgi
            WSGIAuthUserScript /var/www/django_auth.wsgi
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/graphite-web_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/graphite-web_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I also added `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` just to make sure I didn't have any issues with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try using next

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

[The staticfiles app - Django documentation](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/&ei=yMNDUdzuCOvU0gG-uICwBg&usg=AFQjCNGVO9S3PQJXD_ebvNGLKOfJFZytrA&bvm=bv.43828540,d.dmQ)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read through the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to get yourself acquainted with the SO Q&A format.

Comment: This answer looks dangerous.  It overwrites static files.

Comment: No, alejandro is correct.  It's not overwriting the static files from your codebase, it's overwriting the files that Django is serving.  You should set your static_root to be some empty directory, then run collectstatic.  Django essentially collects the files and serves them from the STATIC_ROOT location.  This separates the responsibility for mapping their location from the structure of your codebase, and gives you the ability to use a separate server for the static files.

Comment: Note:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/, where it says that serving your static files directly from the codebase is "grossly inefficient, and probably insecure", and points to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/ for solutions, where it says to use collectstatic.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem when running Django + Apache, the Django admin site misses all styling. This is how I solved it:

*apache conf: httpd-app.conf*

```
Alias /static "/...path/to/your/django.../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
<Directory "/...path/to/your/django.../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The `/...path/to/your/django.../` above, you can find it by `pip show django`